# Add items to array (non-nested) - Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

JS noob here.

I'm trying to add unique values to an array based on a condition, however each time I'm adding an item to the array it will be nested. How can I add items to an array without nesting them?

```
  var Settings = sp.getSheetByName('Settings');
  
  var email_list = Settings.getRange("D2:D").getValues().filter(String);
  var portfolio_list = Settings.getRange("E2:E").getValues().filter(String);
  
  var i;
  var distribution_list = [];
    
  for (i = 0; i < email_list.length +1; i++) {
    if ((portfolio_list[i] == 'someValue') && (distribution_list.indexOf(email_list[i]) == -1)) {
        distribution_list.push(email_list[i]);
    }
  }
```

What I've noticed that .push() adds the elements as a nested array. This way I cannot check it with indexOf() because it never returns -1 when it comes to duplicates.

How could I add an item(s) to an array **only** if it is not present already in array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [Array#flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the 2D array
- Use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store/get unique values.

**Snippet:**

```
const email_list = Settings.getRange(
  'D2:D'
) /* Better to limit range ("D2:D"+Settings.getLastRow())*/
  .getValues()
  .flat() /*Flatten the array*/
  .filter(String);
const portfolio_list = Settings.getRange('E2:E')
  .getValues()
  .flat()
  .filter(String);

const distribution_set = new Set();

for (let i = 0; i < email_list.length /*+1 will throw error*/; i++) {
  if (
    portfolio_list[i] == 'someValue' &&
    !distribution_set.has(
      email_list[i]
    ) /*Added, but not needed as set can only contain unique values*/
  ) {
    distribution_set.add(email_list[i]);
  }
}

/*Instead of a for-loop, you can also do this:
const dSet = new Set(portfolio_list.filter(e => e === 'someValue'));*/

const distribution_list = [...distribution_set]; /*back to array*/
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the helpful comments too!